# Unable to cast object of type 'ADODB.Recordset' to type 'MSDATASRC.DataSource'

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a one migrated Vb6 to c#.net project. When I run this c# solution I got an  **InvalidCastException** like **Unable to cast object of type 'ADODB.Recordset' to type 'MSDATASRC.DataSource'**

at the statement **DataGrid1.DataSource = (MSDATASRC.DataSource)(object)(Module1.rs);**.

where rs is generated as follows:
public static ADODB.Connection conn = null;
public static ADODB.Recordset rs = null;

```
     conn = new ADODB.Connection();
     conn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\myDatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False",String.Empty,String.Empty,-1);

     rs = new ADODB.Recordset();         
     rs.ActiveConnection = conn;
     rs.CursorLocation = (ADODB.CursorLocationEnum)(MSAdodcLib.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient);
     rs.CursorType = (ADODB.CursorTypeEnum)(MSAdodcLib.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic);
     rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic;
     rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

     rs.Open(null,null,ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenUnspecified,ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockUnspecified,-1);
```

Anybody could you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 DataGrid1.DataSource = DataGrid1.DataSource = (MSDATASRC.DataSource)(object)(Module1)
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, I tries with u r code and I got the error like**'Project1.Module1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'**

Comment: I tried like this DataGrid1.DataSource = (MSDATASRC.DataSource)(object)(Module1.rs.Source);. Now I ma bale to load page but I ma unable to get records from the table.